# Genius Messenger 310 Camera turned 180º in Karmic

Tags: 9.10, webcam

I have a problem with the camera - in Ubuntu the image appear turned  180º
Does someone know the solution?

Comment: Turn the camera upside down (180º)? :P

Comment: Yes, It could work, I thought about turning my head too ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/493542).

There is a [workaround you can try](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8925031&postcount=225) if you like.

Answer (score 2):

This is purportedly the "right" way to do it now (the link that user5268 posted is marked as obsolete).  Haven't personally tried it so YMMV

http://radu.cotescu.com/2009/11/05/flipped-images-ubuntu-webcam/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the tutorial in [this page](http://radu.cotescu.com/2009/07/31/resolving-vertically-flipped-images-from-webcams-in-ubuntu/)